# Load and start a Java class dynamically

Tags: java, class

```
Class<? extends Runnable> theClass = 
    Class.forName("C:\Myclass.class").asSubclass(Runnable.class);
Runnable instance = theClass.newInstance();
new Thread(instance).start();
```

I want to write like this `C:\\Myclass.class`

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: So write like this: `C:\\Myclass.class`

Comment: @Maroun85 dont we need to escape `.` as well ??, cuz `.` inregex mean match everything ??

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR No regexes here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Method to dynamically load java class files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219829/method-to-dynamically-load-java-class-files)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik what i meant was, dont we need to escape `.` like '\\.' to be treated as a dot character??

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR Since this is not a regex string, no, we don't

Comment: Thanks for your resp... Its helpful...

Answer (score 1):

`Class.forName()` takes a class name such as `java.lang.Thread` as parameter, not a file path.  You have to load your class by using a dynamic `ClassLoader`

See: [Method to dynamically load java class files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219829/method-to-dynamically-load-java-class-files)

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your `Class.forName()`.

You have to supply the fully qualified class name (FQCN) to this method.

If you want to load a certain class from an external source you have to write your own `ClassLoader`.