# How to load a .class file at runtime for use with JUnitCore.runclasses()

Tags: java, junit, compilation, .class-file, urlclassloader

I am developing a facility that will execute a java unit test.

The system will need to compile a .java file (from outside the working directory) at runtime and "import" the outputted .class file.  This .class file will then be executed using the JUnitCore runClasses() command.  Am I right in thinking that the URLClassLoader is the correct approach?

How should I go about loading the class with the URLClassLoader?  Can the output of this this be passed to the runClasses() method?

Any help with this would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

runClasses() takes Class as a parameter, so it should work with the output from URLClassLoader. You're probably looking for this: [Method to dynamically load java class files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219829/method-to-dynamically-load-java-class-files)

Comment: Thanks, this has sorted my issue.