# Reflection API - ClassNotFound Exception

Tags: java, reflection, classnotfoundexception

Scenario: I have java classes in the folder in a drive. I want to invoke a method, from a specific class, say Regex.
Can I use Reflection API to invoke method ? I have the following code:

```
File dir = new File("H:/TestFolder/sample");
    File[] directoryListing = dir.listFiles();
    if (directoryListing != null) {
        for (File child : directoryListing) {
            File[] dirListing = child.listFiles();
            for (File fileName : dirListing) {
                if (fileName.getName().equals("Regex.java")) {
                    Class<?> clazz;
                    try {

                        clazz = Class.forName("Regex");
                        Constructor<?> ctor = clazz.getConstructor();
                        Object regexClass = ctor.newInstance();
....}
```

I get ClassNotFoundException. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: First of all classes cannot be load from Java source files it has to be compiled. If you want to load compiled class files from a folder check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219829/method-to-dynamically-load-java-class-files)

Comment: I would check that `Regex.class` is in your class path in the default package.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Sir, don't you think that the missing package name in the `Class.forName(..)` is causing this? I have mentioned this in the answer section. Kindly correct me if I am mistaken.

Comment: @DebosmitRay it could be, however if the source was `H:/TestFolder/sample` the package would have to be `sample`

Comment: @PeterLawrey Oh yes. I missed that. I will update the answer. Thanks, sir.

Comment: @DebosmitRay assuming the first package is not `TestFolder` ;)

Comment: BTW Your is a complicated way of saying `Object regexClass = new Regex();` If that doesn't work, your code won't work either.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Oh yes. Absolutely. Please do make any edits that you deem necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The class is actually called `[packageName].Regex` because you've declared it within some package called `[packageName]`.

**Edit**. Peter Lawrey pointed out that if the source was `H:/TestFolder/sample` the package would have to be `sample`. So the class will be called `sample.Regex`, not `Regex`. This is assuming that the base package isn't `TestFolder`. If it is, then `TestFolder.sample.Regex`. I'm sure you get the idea. Please read Mr. Lawrey's comment [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36382810/reflection-api-classnotfound-exception/36382951#comment60383294_36382951).

`Class.forName()` take a class name that specifies the package name. From [[docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29)] for the `className` variable,

> className - the fully qualified name of the desired class.

This specificity should take of the `ClassNotFoundException`.

**Note**. I'm expecting that your `Regex.java` has been compiled to generate a `Regex.class` file. Your IDE should have done this.

Comment: To know which package it is, look at the `package xxx;` line at the start of the `.java` file.  If there is not such line, it is in the default package.

Comment: I don't have a package. It's the JavaProject name. It is Sample (Sorry for the typo sample).

Comment: So, you have no package stated at the top of your file, or is it called `sample` or `Sample`? It would be nice if you update it in the original post. **Sidenote**. If you don't have a package listed, it is good practice to have a package, instead of using `(default package)`.

Answer (score 0):

May be is a silly question but. Did you checked that these classes are in the classpath?

I mean. Is that folder the **src** of your code or is it an external folder you want to inspect and load?

Classes should be in the classpath in order to initalizate their objects via reflection.

Comment: External folder it is. So you meant I cannot inspect and load from an external folder?

Comment: You can inspect. But these files will be like text flat files :-). No like executsble classes.