# Create Classloader with only classes inside specific folder

Tags: java, classloader, urlclassloader

I want to load specific jars in `ScriptEngineManager` using [specific ClassLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngineManager.html#ScriptEngineManager(java.lang.ClassLoader))

> This constructor loads the implementations of ScriptEngineFactory visible to the given ClassLoader using the service provider mechanism.

The problem when I tried to create [Classloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219829/method-to-dynamically-load-java-class-files)

> ```
> File file = new File("c:\\myclasses\\");
>
> try {
> // Convert File to a URL
> URL url = file.toURI().toURL();          // file:/c:/myclasses/
> URL[] urls = new URL[]{url};
>
> // Create a new class loader with the directory
> ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls)
> ```

And I'm getting also class that weren't in class for example Spring

```
 Class cls1 = cl.loadClass("org.springframework.http.HttpStatus");
```

How can I create a clean classloader with only specific folder's classes?

**EDIT**

If it's not possible, can I use in groovy script something equivalent to Rhino's [ClassShutter](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=org.mozilla.javascript.ClassShutter)

> ```
> private static void setJavaClassesVisibleInvisibleSandbox(Context cx)
>  {
>   cx.setClassShutter(new ClassShutter()
>    {
>       public boolean visibleToScripts(String className)
>       {
>           // No Java classes allowed inside scripts
> ```

**EDIT**

When tried @Vinz243 `CustomClassLoader` solution failed to load classes for classes files or jar files from specific folder, even tried `rt.jar`

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.lang
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:662)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:761)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at com.CustomClassLoader.loadClass(CustomClassLoader.java:15)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As specified in the javadoc :

> **`public URLClassLoader(URL[] urls)`**
>
> Constructs a new URLClassLoader for the specified URLs **using the default delegation parent ClassLoade**r. The URLs will be searched in the order specified for classes and resources **after first searching in the parent class loader**. Any URL that ends with a '/' is assumed to refer to a directory. Otherwise, the URL is assumed to refer to a JAR file which will be downloaded and opened as needed.

So you can try to extend `ClassLoader` since the mechanism responsible for loading the parent class is inside `java.lang.ClassLoader#loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean)`

```
    try {
        if (parent != null) {
            c = parent.loadClass(name, false);
        } else {
            c = findBootstrapClassOrNull(name);
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // ClassNotFoundException thrown if class not found
        // from the non-null parent class loader
    }
```

**EDIT**

Not tested, but something like that should do the job:

```
class CustomClassLoader extends URLClassLoader {

    public CustomClassLoader (URL[] urls) throws NoSuchMethodException {
        super(urls);
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?> loadClass (String name, boolean resolve) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        synchronized (getClassLoadingLock(name)) {
            Class<?> aClass = findClass(name);
            if (resolve) {
                resolveClass(aClass);
            }
            return aClass;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ClassLoader can't be accessed `private final ClassLoader parent`

Comment: I mean extend the ClassLoader/URLClassLoader rather modifying the `URLClassLoader` class

Comment: I tried to extend and `parent` can't be used *The field ClassLoader.parent is not visible*

Comment: Why do you need to access parent? Your implementation shouldn't be using it

Comment: I tried your suggestion to *extend `ClassLoader`*  and using `if (parent != null) {`, can you explain your answer?

Comment: I would rather extends URLClassloader, see post edit

Comment: I tried your solution, but now it doesn't recognize classes inside the specific folder or classes inside jars. excpetion: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.minidev.asm.FieldFilter
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 at com.CustomClassLoader.loadClass(CustomClassLoader.java:15)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195915/discussion-between-vinz243-and-user7294900).