# Cal main method from other class by String

Tags: java, string, class

I'm building a class to run the main methods of a few other classes my co-worker build. This works by scanning a folder for files and running every main method neccesary, based on filenames. I had a large chunk of if statements to run the main methods of the classes corresponding with the filenames.

The typical if statement was like:

```
if (f.contains("FileX")) {
                Files.copy(Paths.get("D:\\" + yearmonth.format(date) + "\\" + dateFormat.format(date) + "\\" + f),
                        Paths.get("C:/eclipse-workspace/javarepository/rapporting/" + f),
                        StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                String[] pasStr = new String[] { f };
                FileX.main(pasStr);
}
```

FileX was the string name, the corresponding class has the same name. I would like to skip all the If statements and just do it like this(that doesnt work):

```
                Files.copy(Paths.get("D:\\" + yearmonth.format(date) + "\\" + dateFormat.format(date) + "\\" + f),
                        Paths.get("C:/eclipse-workspace/javarepository/rapporting/" + f),
                        StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                String[] pasStr = new String[] { f };
                FileX.main(pasStr);
}
```

The problem is, of course, the fileX is a string value. So I tried everything I could find, like
`Class cls = Class.forName("FileX");
cls.main(pasStr);`

but I can't find a solution  that works. Anyone who knows of a way to get this working?

Comment: Hello, are you trying to load classes from `.class` files?

Comment: This answer might have what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219829/method-to-dynamically-load-java-class-files