# Retrieve a Class<?> type from a .class file

Tags: java, javafx, reflection

I have a javafx window, and when I drag .class files into it I would like to "transform" them into Class<?>

I tried with Class.forname the problem is that you have to know the package, which is not my case.
And I tried to read the .class file with a buffered reader to retrieve the package inside but of course it is not possible to read a .class file.

So I need to find a way to transform any .class file regardless of its location on the computer into Class<?> in my code.

```java
@Override
    public void handle(DragEvent event) {
        Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
        boolean success = false;
        if (db.hasFiles()) {
            for (File file : db.getFiles()) {
                String fileName = file.getName();
                // Vérifiez si le fichier a l'extension .class
                if (fileName.endsWith(".class")) {

                    //TODO
                    
                    //GlobalView.getInstance().addClassNode(new ClassNode(new Class(  the Class<?> object    )));

                }
            }
        }
        event.setDropCompleted(success);
        event.consume();
    }
```

Comment: "of course it is not possible to read a .class file" - why of course? The Java Class File Format is [well specified](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/jvms-4.html)

Comment: Have a look at this, maybe it helps already to at least get you started: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219829/method-to-dynamically-load-java-class-files

Comment: One thing to note: If you plan on actually loading the class so that you can get an instance of `java.lang.Class`, then any other class files that the given class file depends on must also be loadable. Otherwise, you'll end up with a `ClassNotFoundException` or something similar.

Comment: Another note: you should keep in mind that loading any user-provided code is a security risk so make sure that either the user is trusted, the application doesn't affect other systems (e.g. communicate with a server), and/or you sanitize and check the code (might be hard to do though).

Comment: Seems like an XY problem. What do you plan to *do* with the instance of Class once you have it? i.e. what does `addClassNode` actually do?

Comment: The goal is to create a class diagram generator in javafx. When a person drags a .class file it generates a rectangle with its name, fields, methods...

Comment: @LeonarddooCampione Then you shouldn't actually need to load the class. Perhaps you can provide an alternative ClassNode implementation that works with a BCEL JavaClass (as shown in my answer) instead of a java.lang.Class. The JavaClass instance has all the information about fields and methods without actually loading it.

Comment: @Michael Actually I think that's what I'm going to do. I thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of your problems is that you don't know the package of the class, and you can't reasonably determine it from the filepath.

You can use [Apache Commons BCEL](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/) to parse the file in order to get the package, as well as plenty of other information about it.

```
String path = "/path/to/com/example/MyClass.class";
// org.apache.bcel.classfile.JavaClass and org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser
JavaClass clazz = new ClassParser(path).parse();
String className = clazz.getClassName(); // com.example.MyClass
```

From there, you can use a URLClassLoader to actually load the class by name, provided all the dependencies of that Class are loaded or loadable:

```
String dir = Paths.get(path).getParent().toString() + '/';
URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(
    new URL[]{ new URL("file://" + dir) },
    getClass().getClassLoader()
);
Class<?> myClass = loader.loadClass(className);
```

If the dependencies of the class are not loadable then you'll need to rethink your approach. It's impossible to load a class without its dependencies, and as the user is just dragging and dropping a file, that file may depend on classes that you have no reasonable way of finding.

It may well be the case that the [`JavaClass`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/apidocs/org/apache/bcel/classfile/JavaClass.html) instance returned by BCEL already contains all the information you need, and that you don't actually *need* to load the class at all. You haven't been specific enough about what you're using the Class instance for, so I can't say for certain.